# Generate load base class field

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

I have a Base class with a readonly string field:

```
public class BaseClass {
    readonly String field;
    public BaseClass() {
        field = "random";
    }
}
```

And i'm generating an instance method, inside a class that extends from the Base one via System.Reflection.Emit, which uses that field but i don't seem to be able to access it via:

```
(...)
MethodBuilder methB = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(method, MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(String), new Type[] { typeof(Object) });
ILGenerator methGen = methB.GetILGenerator();
methGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
methGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, typeof(BaseClass).GetField("field"));
(...)
```

The problem is how do i access the field? From the base class or from the current class i'm building in the last case i don't have the Type yet.

Comment: Two immediate problems: (1) The field name is case sensitive. In your example the names do not match. (2) Fields are private by default, so maybe try marking yours with `public`.

Comment: (1) Was an error xD
(2) Since the new class extends that one shouldn't it be protected?

Comment: (2) No. You're thinking of [virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual), I believe.

Comment: Like said before, the readonly field should be explicitly mark protected or public in the base class to be able to see it in a derived class. If the field is not public, you have to also use BindingFlags.NotPublic parameter in your GetField call, because reflection.emit looks for only public members by default.